# How to parse dynamic path parameter in handler request method?

Tags: light-4j

novice Q over Handler functionality - how can I parse dynamic parameter present in the path, i.e. /path/{parameter} in handleRequest method? I've generated an application based on OpenAPI spec

Answer (score 1):

String clientId = exchange.getQueryParameters().get("clientId").getFirst();
We basically normalized the path parameter to query parameter in the handler module.